# Shop vac stopped working

Tags: electrical

I detected a burnt odor just before my shop vac stopped working.  I have taken apart the vac to try to troubleshoot.  Curious about one thing.  Plug vac into electrical outlet and then tested voltage where electric cord connects to vac on/off switch.  Only getting a 10 to 12 volt reading at the this end of the electric cord.  I know the electric outlet is good.  This is at the point before plugged into switch. So, a bad switch would have no impact at this point.  Why is voltage so low.  And would any problem here be associated with a burnt odor.  Or, maybe, the burnt odor is not related to the vac problem.  Opinions? Tnanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because small appliance repair is off topic. Please see the [help].

Comment: questions asking for opinions are not allowed here, because all opinions are "correct"

Comment: Has the electric cord been damaged? How are you measuring voltage, and where?